# Stack Build Profiling Fails Due to tf-random Error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Running `stack build --profile` on my project yields the following error:

```
tf-random-0.5: configure
tf-random-0.5: build
Progress: 1/5
--  While building package tf-random-0.5 using:
      /home/user/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.24.0.0-ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/user/myProject/.stack-work/logs/tf-random-0.5.log

    Configuring tf-random-0.5...
    Building tf-random-0.5...
    Preprocessing library tf-random-0.5...
    [1 of 4] Compiling System.Random.TF.Gen ( src/System/Random/TF/Gen.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/System/Random/TF/Gen.o )
    [2 of 4] Compiling System.Random.TF.Init ( src/System/Random/TF/Init.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/System/Random/TF/Init.o )

    /tmp/stack27695/tf-random-0.5/src/System/Random/TF/Init.hs:94:5: warning: [-Wdeprecations]
        In the use of ‘bitSize’ (imported from Data.Bits):
        Deprecated: "Use 'bitSizeMaybe' or 'finiteBitSize' instead"
    [3 of 4] Compiling System.Random.TF.Instances ( src/System/Random/TF/Instances.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/System/Random/TF/Instances.o )
    [4 of 4] Compiling System.Random.TF ( src/System/Random/TF.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/System/Random/TF.o )
    [1 of 4] Compiling System.Random.TF.Gen ( src/System/Random/TF/Gen.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/System/Random/TF/Gen.p_o )

    /tmp/stack27695/tf-random-0.5/src/System/Random/TF/Gen.hs:18:1: error:
        Failed to load interface for ‘System.Random’
        Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘random-1.1’?
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Note that I have other stack projects on my system which do not yield this error. The only difference between those projects and this one, that I can think of, is that this one makes heavy use of C/C++ FFI.

Finally, I tried adding dependencies on `tf-random` and `random` to my cabal file, but to no avail. Note also I'm not using `random` libraries in my project, and running `stack build` works just fine (I only see these errors when I add the `--profile` tag).

**EDIT:** The output of `ghc-pkg list`.

```
/usr/lib/ghc-8.0.1/package.conf.d
    Cabal-1.24.0.0
    HUnit-1.5.0.0
    QuickCheck-2.9.2
    X11-1.6.1.2
    X11-xft-0.3.1
    array-0.5.1.1
    base-4.9.0.0
    binary-0.8.3.0
    bytestring-0.10.8.1
    call-stack-0.1.0
    containers-0.5.7.1
    data-default-0.7.1.1
    data-default-class-0.1.2.0
    data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1
    data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1
    data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1
    deepseq-1.4.2.0
    directory-1.2.6.2
    dlist-0.8.0.2
    extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
    filepath-1.4.1.0
    ghc-8.0.1
    ghc-boot-8.0.1
    ghc-boot-th-8.0.1
    ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
    ghci-8.0.1
    haskeline-0.7.2.3
    hoopl-3.10.2.1
    hpc-0.6.0.3
    integer-gmp-1.0.0.1
    mtl-2.2.1
    old-locale-1.0.0.7
    old-time-1.1.0.3
    pretty-1.1.3.3
    primitive-0.6.1.0
    process-1.4.2.0
    quickcheck-io-0.1.4
    random-1.1
    rts-1.0
    setlocale-1.0.0.3
    template-haskell-2.11.0.0
    terminfo-0.4.0.2
    tf-random-0.5
    time-1.6.0.1
    transformers-0.5.2.0
    unix-2.7.2.0
    utf8-string-1.0.1.1
    xhtml-3000.2.1
    xmonad-0.12
    xmonad-contrib-0.12
/home/user/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.0.1/package.conf.d
    HUnit-1.5.0.0
    ListLike-4.5
    QuickCheck-2.9.2
    Unixutils-1.54.1
    bzlib-0.5.0.5
    call-stack-0.1.0
    cereal-0.5.4.0
    crypto-api-0.13.2
    entropy-0.3.7
    exceptions-0.8.3
    fmlist-0.9
    generic-deriving-1.11.1
    hscolour-1.24.1
    network-uri-2.6.1.0
    parsec-3.1.11
    primitive-0.6.1.0
    process-extras-0.4.1.4
    pureMD5-2.1.3
    regex-base-0.93.2
    regex-compat-0.95.1
    regex-posix-0.95.2
    regex-tdfa-1.2.2
    sr-extra-1.46.3.2
    stm-2.4.4.1
    syb-0.6
    tagged-0.8.5
    text-1.2.2.1
    tf-random-0.5
    transformers-compat-0.5.1.4
    vector-0.11.0.0
    zlib-0.6.1.2
```

Comment: what is the output of `ghc-pkg list` and did you install haskell from a system package or with stack. Are you maybe using a debian based linux distribution and have installed the `haskell-platform` and/or `random` without `random-prof`

Comment: if you answered the last question with yes - try `apt-get install libghc-random-prof`.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: I'm running Arch Linux. I posted the output of `ghc-pkg list` above. I also installed some Arch Linux packages having keywords like `random` in them, but am getting similar errors.

Comment: i am no expert on arch linux, but when using stack I try to install as little packages as possible with my system - in my case only cabal, alex, happy and ghc is installled - everything else is done by stack. either install the relevant profiling packages as well or - remove them.

Comment: When GHC complains about missing profiling libraries, it often helps to use a stack-managed GHC via `--no-system-ghc`. `--no-system-ghc` was made the default setting in [v1.3.0](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/tag/v1.3.0).